# Angular's FormControl cause an infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, infinite-loop, form-control

I have the following logic:

1.component.ts

```
onChangeRow($event) {
    form.controls["value"].patchValue($event.data.value, { emitEvent: false }); // 
}
```

2.component.ts

```
@Output() changeRow: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  this.changeRow.emit({selfRef: this.selfRef, form: this.formGroup, config: this.config})
})
```

It looks that `patchValue` method in the first component triggers a loop, as its new value is catched by `valueChanges` and the cycle continues until I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. Sometimes it only fires 3 times, sometimes just once.

I try to understand why the emitEvent attribute doesn't work here.

Comment: See if this fixes the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53460744/6513921

Comment: I did but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried to use ``distinctUntilChanged`` but this doesn't seem too effective as well, as I patch several form controls in my first component

Answer (score 2):

Try to set *onlySelf* to *true*, in *patchValue()* options argument.

```
onChangeRow($event) {
    form.controls["value"].patchValue($event.data.value, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false }); 
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! I wish I could have found this on the Angular site first...

Comment: I was caught in an endless loop cause of `control.disable()`
Adding `{ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}` to the `disable` solved my issue